# node-jose cyrillic support, how to?

Tags: javascript, typescript

https://github.com/cisco/node-jose
it's my code example:

```
    let keystore1;
    let keystore2;
    keystore1 = JWK.createKeyStore();
    keystore2 = JWK.createKeyStore();

    const input = { message: { text: 'Привет!' } };

    const priv1 = await keystore1.generate('EC', 'P-256', {
      kid: '1gBdaS-G8RLax2qgObTD94w',
      key_ops:["sign", "decrypt", "unwrap"]
    });
    const priv2 = await keystore2.generate('EC', 'P-256', {
      kid: '2gBdaS-G8RLax2qgObTD94v',
      key_ops:["sign", "decrypt", "unwrap"]
    });

    const pub1 = await JWK.asKey(priv1.toJSON());
    const pub2 = await JWK.asKey(priv2.toJSON());
    const encrypted = await JWE.createEncrypt(
      {
        format: 'compact',
        fields: {
          alg: 'ECDH-ES',
          enc: 'A128CBC-HS256',
          cty: 'json', // replace with JWT if you're encrypting a JWT...
        },
      },
      {
        key: pub2,
      }
    )
      .update(JSON.stringify(input))
      .final();

    console.log('encrypted', encrypted);

    const decrypted = await JWE.createDecrypt(priv2).decrypt(encrypted);

    console.log('decrypted', JSON.parse(decrypted.payload.toString()));
```

// simulate only having access to the public key, usually this is your starting point as you only have access to the public components if you're encrypting a message for someone else.

With latin -  decryption ok!
How to decrypte with cyrillic, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the encoding to the update function.

e.g.`JWE.createEncrypt(...).update(input, "utf8")`

[Doc](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose/blob/1f86e23fc69063aea56974aa7247c2400b7dd50c/lib/jwe/encrypt.js#L111)